# Chrome omnibar showing squares

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

When I got home today my address bar was showing squares instead text. If I type in a website it still works but the address is always squares. I checked the language settings and they are set to English. I also searched google without any luck. Does anyone know what could cause this and how to fix it?

[image: Chrome Omnibar]

Comment: Did you delete any fonts on your system by mistake? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, the only change is that I updated IE to version 10

Comment: Confirmed that it is a font issue. I just noticed I was having problems with the search bar on my start menu doing the same thing and changed the system font from SegoeUI to another font and it fixed the problem. Now I just need to try reinstalling the font.

Comment: @Ripster Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Because I found more issues after I posted that. I just undeleted though because restaring cleared up the remaining problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing SegoeUI (the default font for Win7) and then restarting the pc fixed it.